# How to display django form object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

My problem is when I click in my `tr`, I display a choicefield with  `{{formFacture.description_article}}` but it doesn't work.

When I do `td.innerHTML = "test"` it does work.

Here is my html code:

```
<tbody class="table-article-tbody" id="table_article_tbody">
  {% for ligne in liste_article %}
      <tr id="{{ ligne.ref_article }}">
         <td>{{ ligne.descripton_article }}</td>
         <td>{{ ligne.compte_article }}</td>
      </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{ formFacture.description_article }}</td>
    <td>{{ formFacture.compte_article }}</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
        $('#table_article tr').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if($(this).attr('id') != undefined){
                var $this = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url : "{% url 'updateligneFacture_tem' %}",
                    data: $("#form_facture").serialize(),
                    success : function(data){
                        $('#contenue_fact').html(data);
                        $('#table_article tr:last').remove();
                        var row = $this.attr('id');
                        var tr = document.getElementById(row);
                        var td = tr.insertCell(0);
                        td.innerHTML = "{{ formFacture.description_article }}";
                          alert(tr);

                        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
                    },
                    error : function(){
                        alert("Erreur update !!");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `td.innerHTML = "{{ formFacture.description_article|escape }}";`?

Comment: yes i tried it but the same problem it doesint work

Comment: What is the rendered output of this part of the javascript code?                         `td.innerHTML = "{{ formFacture.description_article }}";`
 And what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error message in the javascript console? Is there a python exception?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying set the click event to a table as:

$("#table_article tr").on("click", ...), but you should assign the event to the tr directly

```
$("#table_article tbody tr").on("click", ...)
```

or

```
$("#table_article_tbody tr").on("click", ...)
```

It's the main reason, you don't set the event to the tr of table correctly.

Also, you can escape the django objects with the filters: safe and scapejs

```
{{ object|safe }} 

{{ object|escapejs }}
```